# JavaScript getAttribute not working

Tags: javascript

```
var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
for (var i=0, n=objects.length;i<n;i++) {
    objects[i].style.display='none';
    var swfurl;
    var j=0;
    while (objects[i].childNodes[j]) {
    if (objects[i].childNodes[j].getAttribute('name') == 'movie') {
            /* DO SOMETHING */ 
    }
    j++;
}
    var newelem = document.createElement('div');
    newelem.id = '678297901246983476'+i;
    objects[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newelem, objects[i]);
    new Gordon.Movie(swfurl, {id: '678297901246983476'+i, width: 500, height: 400});
}
```

It says that getAttribute is not a function of childNodes[j]. What's wrong? I don't see the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the `nodeType` property is 1 (meaning the node is an element) before calling element-specific methods such as `getAttribute()`. Also, forget `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()`: you almost never need them, they're broken in IE and they don't do what you might think. Use equivalent DOM properties instead. In this case:

```
var child = objects[i].childNodes[j];
if (child.nodeType == 1 && child.name == 'movie') {
    /* DO SOMETHING */ 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Remember that [`childNodes`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1451460987) includes text nodes (and comment nodes, if any, and processing instructions if any, etc.). Be sure to check the [`nodeType`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-111237558) before trying to use methods that only [`Element`s](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-745549614) have.

**Update**: Here in 2018, you could use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead, which only includes `Element` children. It's supported by all modern browsers, and by IE8-IE11. (There are some quirks in older IE, see the link for a polyfill to smooth them over.)

Comment: dang, beat me to it.  This is a common issue, since indenting and tidying HTML introduces text nodes that contain only white-space, with one of these text nodes being the first child of the parent element. You can also use `children` to get child elements only. +1

Comment: @Andy E: `children` isn't yet quite well-supported enough to use on the general web, I'd say.

Comment: In 2018, using `.children` is fine.

Comment: @Xufox - Indeed. Seven years. Yikes. How long have I been on this site? *(rhetorical)*

Answer (score -5):

What browser are you using ? If it's IE then you need to use `readAttribute` instead.

Comment: This isn't correct at all.  Internet Explorer has `getAttribute`, it just doesn't work properly pre IE 8.  It should still work in this case.

Comment: Well I assumed he's not targeting only IE8 or above. But I kinda didn't know that it actually works in IE8 - I always used readAttribute for that kind of browser :-D

Comment: there is no `readAttribute` method in any version of Internet Explorer.  It's always been `getAttribute`.  See for yourself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533053(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: My bad, you're right. I probably mixed it up with the one available in the Prototype JS.