# Get attributes of xml child nodes using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to get the Image attributes from an XML file below.

```
<Vehicle id="4120505">
 <DealerName>Unitrans Volkswagen Mokopane</DealerName>
 <Images>
  <Image Id="6060247" ThumbUrl="http://image.blob.ix.co.za/20x90.jpg"/>
 </Images>
</Vehicle>
```

In my JavaScript i used the following:

```
var M = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Images");
   for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
     {
        for(var j = 0; j < M[i].childNodes.length; j++)
         {
           console.log("The value of x is " + 
           M[i].childNodes[j].getAttribute('ThumbUrl'));
         }
     }
```

I am getting an error in console. How best can i get this attribute from the xml data?

Comment: *i am getting an error in console* and what is that error?

Comment: Use `.children` instead of `.childNodes`. `.childNodes` includes `Text` nodes which don’t have attributes. Also, this code can be shortened to `Array.from(xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("Images > *"), (image) => image.getAttribute("ThumbUrl")).forEach((attr) => console.log("The value of x is " + attr));`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript getAttribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595413/javascript-getattribute-not-working)

Comment: Thank you. It now works. Thanks a lot